# \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage} not working

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm having some issues with page numbering in my LaTeX document. I would like the odd numbered pages to display the page number on the left and the even numbered pages to display it on the right.

I've followed the wiki by the book but it always displays the pages on the left side no matter what; http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout

This is what I have so far:

```
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{my name}
\fancyfoot[R]{Assignment Name}
```

Comment: Are you using the `twoside` class option and `\pagestyle{fancy}`?

Comment: Aha! I was missing twoside in my documentclass. 

Thank you =]

Comment: Thanks! And to the folks who closed this - lucky for me the answer was in a comment. You guys were wrong in saying this was "unlikely to help any future visitors." It was exactly what I needed. Thanks to Steveyphil for asking, and for Gonzalo for the answer.